# Reduce size in a csv dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need help regarding the size of my DataFrame. Here is its size:

```
df.shape
(946270, 65)
```

So if we do  `946270*65` is only `61 507 550` cells in total.

I opened it with the function `pd.read_csv("file.csv",sep=";")`
 and its size is `5.43G`.

Is it not huge for this kind of df? Does someone know what the file is so huge and if it exists something to reduce its size?

Comment: Well it really depends on what is in those cells. If they're small integers, or have very few numbers of unique values, things can get small. But if cells are some unique ID or key that's full of characters like '`XWERWFWERWER13123123SRWRSDFSDFWFSDF234'` then things can get very large.

Comment: how nice it solved the issue thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sctruct your data since some .csv files returns values as `string`, like `date`,
`float`, `int` and `boolean`. Then, convert your `csv` file to `parquet`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.to_parquet('output.parquet')
```

Other things you can do:
-Remove null and blank data
-Remove what you don't need

Answer (score 1):

You can read file by chunks and reduce each chunk filtering or aggregating:

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize):
    function_to_reduce(chunk)
```

If You need whole file in memory, you can use [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) lib

Comment: and How can I save it in order to reduce its size ?

Comment: you can save with compression `df.to_csv(file, compression='gzip')`, in my case it reduce size about 6-8 times.

Answer (score 0):

I will present two answers to the refered question:

1. Divide your dataframe in two sections,

```py
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')    
df_1 = len(df) // 2        # Divide the df by 2
half_1 = df.iloc[:df_1,]   # Assign the first half to object
len(first_half)            # Check the length to check the if it is really the half
```

2. Create a **random** sample of the data based on percentage, using the pd.sample() function

```py
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
sampled_df = df.sample(frac=0.3) # Get 30% of the data
len(sampled_df)                  # check length
```

3. Create a sliced sample with specific number of lines, using the pd.sample() function

```py
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
Specific_Rows = df.sample(n=40) # Select 40 random rows of your dataset
print(Specific_Rows)
```